# error svn: OPTIONS could not connect to server

Tags: svn, mac-osx, options

I'm trying to checkout a repository with an http address.
I tried with different machine but I obtained every time time the same error:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk': could not connect to server (http://svn.macports.org)
```

I can't understand the problem, the address is http so I think that is a problem of subversion with http address (the repository is the one for Macport for MAC OS but I think that the problem is not about the repository but is a subversion problem)

Answer (score 2):

As it says, it could not connect to the server.  That address works just fine, so do you have any web filtering, or a proxy configuration that allows your web browser to access that URL, but isn't configured in your SVN client?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm able to ping the address svn.macports.org (also I can open the address from Safari), so I supposed that it was not a connection problem. Is there other way to verify if there are web filtering?  Anyway thanks for the answer!

Comment: A proxy (with direct connections blocked) would allow your browser to access the url, but not the SVN client.  Try `telnet svn.macports.org 80` - if that fails to connect, then that's the cause.